# RxSwift: Does disposed(by: disposeBag) actually work?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, rx-swift

I noticed when running the Rx debug code from the getting started section (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#debugging-memory-leaks), my resource total does not decrease when using disposed(by: disposeBag) on a subscription. However, if I instead keep a reference to the subscription and call dispose() on it, the resource total decreases.

I use disposed(by:) because I thought it was an easy way to accomplish the same thing, although now I am not sure. Should I avoid relying on this method for the disposal of my subscriptions?

**Note**: If it matters, I use [weak self] in the closures of my subscriptions.

Answer (score 2):

The dispose bag will call disposed on all the disposables it is holding when it gets `deinit`ed. It is likely that your view controller is not going out of scope, or you are expecting it to dispose the objects before that point.